# How can I run guvcview with a different video source on Ubuntu 22.10 Gnome?

Tags: gnome, usb, webcam, 22.10, guvcview

I'm on Ubuntu 22.10 and Gnome 43.

I can't choose a video source easly into menus from guvcview. I've a laptop with it's own webcam and an USB attached digital microscope with UVC standard interface.

But on guvcview there's not a menu to select source like on Cheese.

The only way to change the device is to run from bash using command

```
guvcview -d /dev/videoX
```

With X the number assigned by the system when the microscope is connected.

Answer (score 0):

On guvcview 2.1 I have here there's "Video Controls" tab with the device selector:

[image]